# Any Latent Semantic Indexing?

Tags: java, latent-semantic-indexing

Is there any open source implementation of [LSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_semantic_indexing) in Java? I want to use that library for my project. I have seen jLSI but it implements some other model of LSI. I want a standard model.

Comment: Thanks for adding the comments about jLSI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you considered LDA (Latent Dirichlet allocation)? I haven't really either, but I encountered the same problem with LSI recently (patents). From what I understand LDA is a related/more powerful technique. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_Dirichlet_allocation apparently has some links to open-source implementations.

Answer (score 1):

A google search for java LSI leads to [a similar question](http://old.nabble.com/lsi-as-indexing-algorithm-with-lucene-td22573282.html) that recommends SemanticVectors.  A package built on top of Lucene that is 'similar' to LSI.  I don't know if it's closer than the jLSI implementation.

That thread also mentions that LSI is patented and there aren't a lot of implementations of it.  So if you need a standard implementation you may have to use a language other than java.

Answer (score 1):

The [S-Space Package](http://code.google.com/p/airhead-research/wiki/LatentSemanticAnalysis) has an open source version of LSA, with bindings for the LSI document vectors.  (Both approaches operate on the same term-document matrix and are equivalent except in the output.)  It's a fairly scalable approach that uses the thin-SVD.  I've used it to run LSI on all of Wikipedia with no issue (after removing the infrequent terms with less than 5 occurrences).

As Scott Ray mentioned, the SemanticVectors package also has a good LSI implementation that recently switched to using the same thin-SVD (SVDLIBJ), so you might check that out as if you hadn't before.

Answer (score 1):

a google search for NLP tools provide this [slides](http://128.206.119.157/nlp/papers/NLPTools.pdf) which i think helps ...

Answer (score 0):

I believe that LSA/LSI was patented in 1989, which means the patent should have just expired. Hopefully we will see some nice open source applications soon.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the Semantic Vector package?

http://code.google.com/p/semanticvectors/