# Need help in latent semantic indexing

Tags: java, algorithm, math, latent-semantic-indexing

I am sorry, if my question sounds stupid :)
Can you please recommend me any pseudo code or good algo for LSI implementation in java?
I am not math expert. I tried to read some articles on wikipedia and other websites about
LSI ( latent semantic indexing ) they were full of math.
I know LSI is full of math. But if i see some source code or algo. I understand things more
easily. That's why i asked here, because so many GURU are here !
Thanks in advance

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746568/latent-semantic-indexing-in-java

Comment: Thanks Amit, But if you read my question. So it is different. Even if you think it's same then you can't find some good answer there :)

Comment: Do we always have to reduce the dimension in lsa ? cant we just use the v matrix to find the similarity between the documents and the u matrix to find the similarity between the terms ?

Answer (score 14):

An idea of LSA is based on one assumption: **the more two words occur in same documents, the more similar they are**. Indeed, we can expect that words "programming" and "algorithm" will occur in same documents much more often then, say, "programming" and "dog-breeding".

Same for documents: **the more common/similar words two documents have, the more similar themselves they are**. So, you can express similarity of documents by frequencies of words and vice versa.

Knowing this, we can construct a **co-occurrence matrix**, where column names represent documents, row names - words and each `cells[i][j]` represents frequency of word `words[i]` in document `documents[j]`. Frequency may be computed in many ways, IIRC, original LSA uses [tf-idf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) index.

Having such matrix, you can find similarity of two documents by comparing corresponding columns. How to compare them? Again, there are several ways. The most popular is a **cosine distance**. You must remember from school maths, that matrix may be treated as a bunch of vectors, so each column is just a vector in some multidimensional space. That's why this model is called **"Vector Space Model"**. More on VSM and cosine distance [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space_model).

But we have one problem with such matrix: it is big. Very very big. Working with it is too computationally expensive, so we have to **reduce it** somehow. LSA uses [SVD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) technique to keep the most "important" vectors. After reduction matrix is ready to use.

So, algorithm for LSA will look something like this:

1. Collect **all documents** and **all unique words** from them.
2. Extract **frequency information** and build **co-occurrence matrix**.
3. **Reduce** matrix with SVD.

If you're going to write LSA library by yourself, the good point to start is [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html) search engine, which will make much easier steps 1 and 2, and some implementation of high-dimensional matrices with SVD capability like [Parallel Colt](http://sites.google.com/site/piotrwendykier/software/parallelcolt) or [UJMP](http://www.ujmp.org/).

Also pay attention to other techinques, which grown up from LSA, like [Random Indexing](http://www.sics.se/~mange/papers/RI_intro.pdf). RI uses same idea and shows approximately same results, but doesn't use full matrix stage and is completely incremental, which makes it much more computationally efficient.

Comment: Hi i have been working on lsa lately . Do we always have to reduce the dimensions of the diagonal matrix . My need is to find the similarity between two documents . Is it ok if i take the v matrix alone and use it to find the similarity . I read this approach in this paper : http://www.miislita.com/information-retrieval-tutorial/svd-lsi-tutorial-4-lsi-how-to-calculations.html

Comment: @CTsiddharth: if you don't want to reduce your dimensionality, there's no need in SVD and thus `V` matrix at all - you can use original term-document matrix as is. However, dimensionality reduction gives you 2 big advantages: 1) it reduces noise; 2) it makes document similarity computation much more fast (less elements to compare). So, it makes sense to use full matrix for relatively small corpora (say, < 5000 documents), for larger documents you need complete dimensionality reduction (SVD + selecting k first vectors).

Comment: In my case , i have 35 documents and around 1500 words . If i do an svd the v matrix becomes a 35*35 . So can i use this 35*35 matrix to find the similarity instead of a 1500*35  ? this has been one question i have been thinking of for quite a while

Comment: And also please help me answer this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9582291/how-do-we-decide-the-number-of-dimensions-for-latent-semantic-analysis

Comment: @CTsiddharth: when you reduce dimensions, you filter noise, but also you lose some information. So there's no single answer to your question - it all depends on you dataset. Make some test set and check results for both full and reduced dataset. Same thing to your another question - try different values for reduced dimensions and take the best.

Comment: good description on LSA! but I have a question. if we have a word and then we want to find that this word is related to which part of what document(assuming we have several-not too many- documents) , then is it possible to use this technique to do so?

Comment: @user1064929: "document" is pretty abstract concept. For example, if you try to analyse web site, you can consider it all as a single document, each web page as a document or even each paragraph as a document. In a later case co-occurrence matrix will show how often each word occurs in each paragraph. Does it answer your question?

Comment: so we dont have to have many **words** to compare with many**documents**? comparing one word with many documents to see what is the relevancy of the each documents to the **single** word is still possible in this case?

Comment: @user1064929: using multiple words is recommended, since together they uncover context, but even single word ("document" consisting of a single word) should do the job in most cases. However, if your ultimate goal is to get documents (or document parts) from the word, it makes sense to take a look at information retrieval methods. If you have concrete task and need recommendation, you can always post detailed questions here, on [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) or [DataScience](http://datascience.stackexchange.com/) (depending on what it is about more).

Answer (score 2):

This maybe a bit late but I always liked Sujit Pal's blog http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2008/09/ir-math-with-java-tf-idf-and-lsi.html and I have written a bit on my site if you are interested.

The process is way less complicated than it is often written up as. And really all you need is a library that can do single value decomposition of a matrix.

If you are interested I can explain in a couple of the short take away bits:

1) you create a matrix/dataset/etc with word counts of various documents - the different documents will be your columns and the rows the distinct words.

2) Once you've created the matrix you use a library like Jama (for Java) or SmartMathLibrary (for C#) and run the single value decomposition. All this does is take your original matrix and break it up in to three different parts/matrix that essentially represent your documents, your words, and kind of a multiplier (sigma) these are called the vectors.

3) Once you have you word, document, sigma vectors you shrink them equally (k) by just copying smaller parts of the vector/matrix and then multiply them back together. By shrinking them it kind of normalizes your data and this is LSI.

here are some fairly clear resources:

http://puffinwarellc.com/index.php/news-and-articles/articles/30-singular-value-decomposition-tutorial.html

http://lsa.colorado.edu/papers/JASIS.lsi.90.pdf
http://www.soe.ucsc.edu/classes/cmps290c/Spring07/proj/Flynn_talk.pdf

Hope this help you out a bit.

Eric

Comment: Hi, I learned alot meanwhile. But still your answer is very helpfull +1. I saw sujit pall blog too. It is good but i don't agree with his results. I asked him when there is not context similarity between two documents why it is saying 100% same. He couldn't answer it. Now i am looking how can I use LDA other than LSI. Is it possible to use LDA for this purpose????