# Number of Latent Semantic Indexing topics

Tags: topic-modeling, gensim, latent-semantic-indexing

I'm using gensim's package to implement LSI on a corpus. My goal is to find out the most frequently occurring distinct topics that appear in the corpus.

If I don't know the number of topics that are in the corpus (I'd estimate anywhere from 5 to 20), what is the best approach in setting the number of topics that LSI should search for? Is it better to look for a large number of topics (20-30), or a small number of topics (~5)?

Comment: You can find a create answer to a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9759218/230636

Answer (score 4):

[From Radim himself:](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gensim/g8qruo_5YYs)

> that's a good question, but unfortunately without a good answer.
>
> It is not true that increasing the number of dimensions always 
>   improves retrieval accuracy. In fact, if you use all the dimensions 
>   (=full rank of the training matrix), LSI will give you exactly the 
>   same documents that you entered in, so LSI would become pointless.
>
> If you're interested in the math side of it, have a look at this 
>   issue: https://github.com/piskvorky/gensim/issues/28  Otherwise, just
>   set the dimensions to a few hundred~thousand which is  the accepted
>   standard. Or try several different choices, measure the  accuracy and
>   select dimensionality that works the best on your  problem.
>
> Best,  Radim

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do sometimes when I'm confused. Since you've already narrowed down to your topics from 5-20, you can iterate b/w some of these values and see which value fits the best.

```
##Declare values for N_TOPICS
for i in lda.show_topics(topics=-N_TOPICS, topn=20, log=False, formatted=True): 
  print "TOPIC {0}: {1}\n".format(count, i)
```